# CSS timer to execute actions in steps

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure that what I'm asking for *can* be done at all. If it can't that'd be the answer.

EDIT: The example below is a concrete case. However my question is primarily how to do *anything* in steps as opposed to gradually.

How can I use CSS without JavaScript to scroll a div in steps? i.e. What I have is a div that is 3 times as wide as its container div, and I want the container to scroll the inner div every couple of seconds. First to show the first third, then the second, then the third, and then return to the first. And so on.

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100px;  overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:auto; ">
    <div style="width:300%; height:100px;">abc</div>
</div>
```

I was looking into `animation` but that seems to be for gradual movement. Is there a way to make it 'jump' as I've outlined above?

Comment: Don't think you can do it using scroll, although you can move it with position absolute, and animate the left and right position.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa That'd be fine. My question is primarily how to do anything in steps.

Comment: I think that  better approach is to have 3 different div's with 100% width and as mentioned by @ZohirSalakCeNa position them absolutely and keep second and third ones out of screen, then use CSS animation to move them one by one in to the visible area, or use visibility attribute to make immediate rendering

Comment: @Banzay Fine. But how would I do that? I edited my question to make it clear that my main challenge here is how to do _anything_ in steps (as opposed to gradually) using CSS but not JaveScript.

Comment: @ispiro, please would you show what you achieved and where you stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck at how to create a timer in CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too sure if this might help but you can do percentages in the keyframes to get something like this, which you could apply to a gallery for example.
So the timer here is 9s divided by 3.

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 9s infinite;
    animation: mymove 9s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0% {left: 0px;}
    20%{left: 0px;}
    40% {left: 100px;}
    60%{left:100px;}
    80%{left:200px;}
    100% {left: 200px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    0% {left: 0px;}
    20%{left: 0px;}
    40% {left: 100px;}
    60%{left:100px;}
    80%{left:200px;}
    100% {left: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: While this answer might need some tweaking for other real case scenarios, this is the proper solution :)

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I'm really tired and headed into bed now, so I encourage anyone to build upon this :)

Comment: Thank you very much. So the key is to have 2 keyframes of the same value, which then stops the animation until the next keyframe. I accepted this answer because it was the most succinct.

Answer (score 2):

Here i set multiple background to the div to mimic more content.

As the previous answer showed if your desired end result is for the div to scroll to the second half wait a bit then move to next etc.., adding more breakpoints to the animation should do it. keep in mind that the animation is merely a visual effect.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.parent {
    
    width: 90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.kid>* {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.kid {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, red), linear-gradient(to right, orange, orange), linear-gradient(to right, yellow, yellow);
    background-position: 0% 0, 50% 0, 100% 0;
    background-size: calc(100%/3) 100%, calc(100%/3) 100%, calc(100%/3) 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 300%;
    height: 100px;
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
    0% {
        left: 0%;
    }

    30% {
        left: 0%;
    }

    40% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    60% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    70% {
        left: -200%;
    }
    
    80% {
        left: -200%;
    }

    100% {
        left: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="kid">
    <p>I'm a P Tag</p>
    <div>I'm a div Tag</div>
    <h1>I'm a h1 Tag</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can drop 5, 40 and 95% step.

Comment: All answers were great. But I can only can only choose one. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

To have an animation give the appearance of being paused at certain times, keep the attributes you're animating exactly the same between keyframe percentages:

```
0% {
  color: green;
}
10% {
  color: red;
}
90% {
  color: red;
}
100% {
  color: blue;
}
```

The above keyframes will animate from green to red at 10% completion, but then stay red until 90%, giving the appearance that the animation is completing in steps. We can do something similar with your sliding div:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: slide 9s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  25.333% {
    left: 0;
  }
  33.333% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  58.666% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66.666% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  92% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

.inner div {
  width: 33.333%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="red">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="green">
      C
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the keyframe percentages look strange, it's because I've divided the "steps" into equal portions of time, which is thirds.

Comment: Might wanna add `alternate` to the animation.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa OP says "show the first third, then the second, then the third, and then return to the first." Adding alternate would cause the second slide to show after both the first and the third, which is not the order that is requested.

Comment: All answers were great. But I can only can only choose one. Thank you very much for your answer!